# How to get BitBucket branch url?

Tags: bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repository and I know i can click on Actions tab and click on clone to get the http url of the repository. Now, I have multiple branches in the repository and I am planning to use Jenkins CI to build from a particular branch. Is there a way to get the url of the specific branch in my repository?

Regards

Answer (score 12):

It should be

```
https://bitbucket.org/[username]/[repo_name]/branch/[branch_name]
```

Just replace username, repo_name, and branch_name with your own information.

You can git clone the branch with its URL:

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/[username]/[repo_name]/branch/[branch_name]
```

Comment: Thanks Chong. My repository url looks in the following format. http://[username]/[project_name]/[repo_name]/repo.git Should I add the branch name before repo.git ?

Comment: @Anurag, have you tried the URL I post here? How did it go?