# How to upload local folder to an existing repository in bitbucket?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

My manager in internship asked me to upload the project i created to a new repository,

I inserted the ssh key and so on . Anyway right now i have to upload the entire folder to bitbucket repo, I tried by`git init` ,  `git add .` ,`git commit -a -m "commit name"` and then `git push`.

There is something that i missed?

Comment: Did you add the remote? `git remote add origin <URL>`

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Where do i get this URL ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274595/how-to-get-bitbucket-branch-url

Comment: @EncryptedWatermelon Yes i did , with ssh and http as well , but got the same eror say : 'The syntax of the command is incorrect. '