# How to get Bitbucket/Git URL for a specific branch?

Tags: bitbucket, informatica-powercenter

I use bitbucket but I need to pull a specific branch using the git url.
My git url look like:

```
https://bitbucket.com/scm/<project_name>/<repo_name>.git
```

I need to pull specific branch though so I tried:

```
    https://bitbucket.com/<username>/scm/<project_name>/<repo_name>/branch/<branch_name>
    https://bitbucket.com/<project_name>/<repo_name>/branch/<branch_name>
    https://bitbucket.com/scm/<project_name>/<repo_name>/branch/<branch_name>
    https://bitbucket.com/scm/<project_name>/<repo_name>.git#<branch_name>
```

I keep getting errors like 501 or not found

The goal is to connect my repository to Informatica https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/application-service-guide/model-repository-service/version-control-for-the-model-repository-service/configure-and-synchronize-a-model-repository-after-changing-vers.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get BitBucket branch url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38274595/how-to-get-bitbucket-branch-url)

Comment: @jthill I tried these solutions but it did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you are trying to do.

If you have already cloned your repo, you can pull a specific branch using the url instead of the name of your remote.

```
# You normally pull with this command:
git pull origin my_branch

# You can pull using the URL instead:
git pull bitbucket.com/scm/<project_name>/<repo_name>.git my_branch
```

If you have not yet cloned your repo, you can clone a specific branch:

```
git clone --branch my_branch bitbucket.com/scm/<project_name>/<repo_name>.git
```

Comment: Thank you. However I cannot use the git commands. I'm trying to connect to Informatica and specify a branch as part of the http url. Informatica doesn't let me use a command line https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-4-0/application-service-guide/model-repository-service/version-control-for-the-model-repository-service/configure-and-synchronize-a-model-repository-after-changing-vers.html

Comment: That seems to be a pretty big limitation, you might want to request this feature, even more if you are paying for this product.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to pull specific branch though so I tried:

Those all seem like reasonable ways to do it for http urls, Git uses a way that doesn't depend on any specific server's url format

```
git remote add somename u://r/l -t branch
```

and you can repeat the `-t branch` option as many times as there are branches you'd like to track, or just let it default to all branches.

If you don't want tags, add `--no-tags`. I usually don't for sideband repos like this, I count it as a minor wart, probably too late or anyway not worth it to fix, that `git remote add` doesn't default to this for any remote not named `origin`.

Then

```
git fetch somename
```

brings the tracking refs up to date.

Comment: I need to use the http url because it's for a CICD process that will not let me input the actual command, only the git URL

Comment: That's fine, but if that process won't talk to Git you probably shouldn't be asking this question with a Git tag. Try what I suggest, it's difficult to imagine what sort of mindset would lead to building a sort of git-history server that won't talk to git.

Comment: What's your CICD tool? I'm surprised that it does not let you specify a branch. Most of them let you specify either a branch or a tag to be used when pulling code.